# How to create a beautifully aligned solution for exercises?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

Basically, I'm writing solution for the exercises on the textbook. And I want something like this:

[image]

As you can see, sub-problems are aligned after the problem number and the formulas are aligned after each sub-problems.

I've tried `\tabular` but I can't get what I wanted. Any suggestion?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Both answers from `Mythio` and 'barbara beeton' are very detailed and helpful! Since Mythio's answer is more strait forward, I am giving the best answer to Mythio. But I'll use barbara beeton's though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish a result that is nicely aligned it is easy to use the `align` environment, which is part of the `amsmath` package.

You can accomplish this with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \intertext{2.4-14}
    \intertext{(a)}
    f(x) &= \begin{dcases}
                \frac{125}{216} & x = -1,\\
                \frac{75}{216} & x = 1,\\
                \frac{15}{216} & x = 2,\\
                \frac{1}{216} & x = 3;
            \end{dcases} \\
    \intertext{(b)}
    \mu &= (-1) \cdot \frac{125}{216} + (1) \cdot \frac{75}{216} + (2) \cdot \frac{15}{216} + (3) \cdot \frac{1}{216} = -\frac{17}{216};\\
    \sigma^2 &= E(X^2) - \mu^2 = \frac{269}{216} - \left( -\frac{17}{216} \right) = 1.2392;\\
    \sigma &= 1.11; \\
    \intertext{(c)}
    &  \text{See Figure 2.4-14.} \\
    \intertext{(d)}
    \overline{x} &= \frac{-1}{100} = -0.01;  \\
    s^2 &= \frac{100(129)-(-1)^2}{100(99)} = 1.30.29; \\
    s &= 1.14.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The `mathtools` package is used, because it is needed for the `dcases` environment in the answer for `(a)`. The `mathtools` package automatically loads the `amsmath` package that you also need.

The result looks like this:

[image: result]

Comment: That's helpful. But there's no newline between `2.4-14` and `(a)` in the picture I posted. Is there any way to get the result in the picture?

Comment: @Stanley; you can replace the first two `intertext` commands with  `\intertext{2.4-14 \newline{} (a)}` to remove the extra newline.

Comment: @Stanley; If this answers your question, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted by checking the little tick, left at the top of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

here's an alternate approach, using `tabbing` with `aligned` from `amsmath`.  remember that `aligned` can be used in-line as well as in displays, and the `[t]` option will ensure that the first line is aligned with the current baseline.  note that when `cases` is used, the local baseline is the portion preceding the brace, so instead of "topping" it, it was started on a new line, and "backspaced" vertically.

[image: output of example code]

here's the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\0}{\phantom{0}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
\0 2.4-14\enspace \=(a)\enspace \= \\[-\baselineskip]
\>\>  $\begin{aligned}
    f(x) &=
    \begin{cases}
        125/216, & x = -1, \\
      \0 75/216, & x = 1, \\
      \0 15/216, & x = 2, \\
     \0\0 1/216, & x = 3;
    \end{cases}
  \end{aligned}$\\[6pt]
\>(b) \>
  $\begin{aligned}[t]
    \enspace \mu\ \ &={}\ (-1) \cdot \frac{125}{216}
                      + (1) \cdot \frac{75}{216}
                      + (2) \cdot \frac{15}{216}
                      + (3) \cdot \frac{1}{216} = -\frac{17}{216}\,;\\
    \sigma^2 \ \ &={}\ E(X^2) - \mu^2 = \frac{269}{216}
                      -\bigl( -\frac{17}{216} \bigr)^2 = 1.2392;\\
    \sigma \ \ &={}\  1.11;
  \end{aligned}$\\[6pt]
\>(c) \>See Figure 2.4-14.\\[6pt]
\>(d) \>
  $\begin{aligned}[t]
    \enspace \overline{x}\ \ &={}\ \frac{-1}{100} = -0.01;\\
    s^2 \ \ &={}\ \frac{100(129) - (-1)^2}{100(99)} = 1.3029;\\
    s \ \ &={}\ 1.14.
  \end{aligned}$
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Quick questions: What do `\\[-\baselineskip]` and `\\[6pt]` do?

Comment: @Stanley -- the dimensions in the brackets say how much space to move vertically.  the (positive) `6pt` adds extra space between "items", and the (negative) `-\baselineskip` moves back up one line to place the first line of that group visually on the same line as the "item number".

Comment: @barbarabeeton; Interesting approach, definitely better if tight for space.